# 7 Day Chart in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

How would I create a 7 day chart for days Monday to Sunday and plot data on said days?

So far I've tried;

```
weekdayname(weekday(Fields!Date.Value))
```

This is pulling the data by day name but its not Monday to Sunday it's whatever the day was on that data.

```
Category = Date
Values = Status
Series = Status
```

3 Column's of Data

Name - Status - Date

I want to plot the Status of each Name on a 7 day chart.

[image]

[image]

Comment: *"its not Monday to Sunday it's whatever the day was on that data"* Why would you not want the data for the day the data is on?

Comment: I meant my X Axis is showing Wednesday to Monday instead of Monday to Friday.

Comment: I added a sample few columns, the same Car may have different statuses on different days and I wanted to plot that on the chart. So it might run on Monday but be broken on Wednesday

Comment: How does that data correspond to that line graph? I can't see 8 Wednesday's in your data.

Comment: Why does that matter? There are over 15000 records, I posted sample made up data. The line graph is also made up. My question is how do I create a line graph, if I knew how to make the line graph I wouldnt be here.

Comment: *"Why does that matter?"* Because if we don;t know what the end result for the sample data is, how can we hope to get the right result, when we don't know what that is.

Comment: Also, please do provide sample data as `text`, not as an image so we don't need to transcribe it.

Comment: do you want to "fill in the gaps" when there is no data.. do you always want to show Monday to Sunday? even if you had no data for a particular day.. for example?

Answer (score 0):

This one should get you there:

```
USE tempdb;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.SampleData 
(
    Car int,
    SampleDate date,
    [Status] varchar(20)
);
GO

INSERT dbo.SampleData (Car, SampleDate, [Status])
VALUES (1, '20190916', 'Running'),
       (2, '20190914', 'Running'),
       (3, '20190913', 'Broken'),
       (4, '20190912', 'Running'),
       (5, '20190911', 'Running'),
       (1, '20190908', 'Broken'),
       (3, '20190905', 'Running'),
       (1, '20190902', 'Running');
GO

SELECT DATENAME(weekday, sd.SampleDate) AS [Name],
       SUM(CASE WHEN [Status] = 'Running' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Status]
FROM dbo.SampleData AS sd
GROUP BY DATENAME(weekday, sd.SampleDate);
GO
```

I presume that it's summing up the days that it's running, by day name.

If so, just plot the output of the SELECT statement.

Hope that helps.